# Rewrite Rule is not working well

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting

I am investigating Rewrite Rule of Apache and not using .htaccess but virtual host setting for writing them.

Here I have 2 questions:

1. I can use "RewriteRule blog_rss.xml blog_rss.php" but cannot use "RewriteRule ^blog_rss.xml$ blog_rss.php", why?
2. Even the first script is working, it doesn't change to the RSS style what I want. Should I set handler for it with Rewrite Rule?

Thanks for answering this question.

Update: Here is the scripts about rewrite rule.

```
<Directory />
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
  RewriteRule ^blog_rss\.xml$ blog_rss.php
 </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: `^blog_rss.xml$` is a specific match given the `.htaccess` is on the root folder of your domain it will only match if the URL was `http://domain.com/blog_rss.xml`, is that the case? How the resulting page display the RSS you can fix on your PHP code by changing the header output.

Comment: Hmm I am using virtual host setting and I don't know if it is as same as the setting of .htaccess. So is that meaning ^blog_rss\.xml$ is not suitable for VS setting?

Furthermore, so I found that the 2nd issue is only get from using Chrome but Firefox is working well.

Comment: If you're using it on the `virtualhost` directly then yes. That would be wrong as on the `virtualhost` it starts with `/` so it would have to be `^/blog_rss.xml$` instead of what you have.

Comment: I have tried to change it to both ^/blog_rss.xml$ and ^/blog_rss\.xml$ but they are still not working at all...

Comment: Well without further knowing what other rules you have as well as how is the domain and folder layout you're trying to use it with, its hard to tell.

Comment: I have updated the questions and please take a look on the script, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers. For V-host, I found the reason finally.

According to [RewriteRule in htaccess vs httpd.conf](http://tltech.com/info/rewriterule-in-htaccess-vs-httpd-conf/), the Directory path should be the same as the website base path. For example, if the root directory is /var/www/, the `<Directory>` should set /var/www/ or it will detect the root path of the server.

Answer (score 0):

No you shouldn't set a [handler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_h). Doing so will force the PHP code at `blog_rss.php` to execute as XML. This would result in the entire file being responded with an XML Mime type, *which may present major security issues*.

However, in the `blog_rss.php` file before completing the response you might want to set the response type to that of an RSS file.

**blog_rss.php**

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

**v-host**

```
<Directory />
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
  RewriteRule ^blog_rss\.xml$ blog_rss.php
 </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Resource: [electrictoolbox.com](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/rss-php-content-type/)